# React redux multiple requests in one action creator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, redux, react-redux

I want to make 2 request in a row, kinda in a waterfall fashion. I want to first request a specific pokemon, and then based on the returned obj's payload's type, I want to request more information. I thought it would be best to separate this out to several action creators but feel weird that `fetchPokemon` ends with another fetch. Is this best practice?

```
export const fetchPokemon = function (pokemonName) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestPokemon(pokemonName))
    const requestURL = `http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}/`
    return $.ajax({
      url: requestURL,
    }).done(function (data) {
      dispatch(receivePokemon(data))
      fetchPokeTypeInfo(data.types[0].type.url)
    })
  }
}

...

export const fetchPokemonTypeInfo = function (url) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch(requestPokemonTypeInfo(url))
    return $.ajax({
      url: url,
    }).done(function (data) {
      dispatch(receivePokemonTypeInfo(data))
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's anything particularly wrong with breaking these two up.  One question I'd ask is: "Would I ever call fetchPokemonTypeInfo() directly, not from fetchPokemon()?".  If not, then I'd just return the second .ajax call from the .done() function in the first.  If the first call is always a dep, it seems easier to reason about what is happening if they just nest.  Also, if you do want to keep them separate you'll need to pass the dispatch function as well as the url to the second function, otherwise dispatch is undefined in fetchPokemonTypeInfo().

**Update:**

You could nest the second call in the first like this:

```
export const fetchPokemon = function (pokemonName) {
    return function (dispatch) {
        dispatch(requestPokemon(pokemonName));
        const requestURL = `http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}/`;
        return $.ajax({
            url: requestURL,
        }).done(function (data) {
            dispatch(receivePokemon(data));
            dispatch(requestPokemonTypeInfo(data.types[0].type.url));

            return $.ajax({
                url: data.types[0].type.url,
            }).done(function (data) {
                dispatch(receivePokemonTypeInfo(data));
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show me how you would nest it? i'm not sure how that is possible because doesn't each async call have to go through the thunk? how can i next a thunk inside a thunk?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, which provides clean and predictable solution.

If you are using redux, you can make use of middleware to make your API calls. In addition, in your middleware you can extend its functionality by allowing taking multiple requests (perhaps in array), and resolving them altogether before returning success Promise.

Check this link for reference:
https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/real-world/middleware/api.js

This is an functional middleware, but you have to extend it to support multiple requests :) Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use redux-saga https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga

Note: the following code is just a concept, you would need to adjust it per your needs.

```
function* fetchPokemon(action) {
   try {
      //fetch1
      const pokemon = yield call(Api.fetchPokemon, action.payload.pokemonId);
      //this action will execute only after fetch1 is successful
      yield put({type: "FETCH_POKEMON_SUCCEEDED", payload: pokemon});
      //fetch2
      const pokemonInfo = yield call(Api.fetchPokemonInfo, types[0].type.url)
      // execute after fetch2 is successful 
      yield put({type: "FETCH_POKEMON_INFO_SUCCEEDED", payload: pokemonInfo})
   } catch (e) {
      yield put({type: "FETCH_FAILED", message: e.message});
   }
}

// wait for an action and fire a saga
function* watchFetchPokemonRequest() {
  yield* take("FETCH_POKEMON_REQUESTED", fetchPokemon);
}
```

Sagas use Generators, which "make" your async code synchronous. That way you don't need to deal with callback in promises etc. It's a nice and clean way of describing side-effect of your application.